# CSS color not working on link

Tags: html, css

When visiting the page in *Incognito* (removing `:visited` styles) the link's text is **blue**, but it should be **white**.

```css
.button { 
    color:#ffffff; /* white */
    background:#d8eaf0; 
 }
 .button:visited { 
    color:#ffffff; /* white */
    background:#d8eaf0;
 }
 .button:hover {
    color:#ffffff; /* white */
    background:#3838a5;
 }
 .button:active { 
    color:#ffffff; /* white */
    background:#d8eaf0;
 }
```

```html
<a href="example.com" style="text-decoration: none" class="button">text</a>
```

Comment: In your css you have `button{background:#d8eaf0; }` , so you have a button with background light blue

Comment: Well, I tried to run your code and it is working fine in `incognito` ans working exactly as in normal mode.

Comment: @LuisP.A.  The issue was the text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where your ".button" CSS style is, change it to ".button:link".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92621/discussion-between-jess-and-dani-springer).

Comment: I seen you had another problem with your footer? Give me a yell if you would like me to assist in fixing that problem.

Comment: Go to your chat room for that topic

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `position` to `absolute`. And if that still doesn't work, go onto incognito mode and go on `inspect element` and check to see if the text box is overlapping.

If nothing still works, use `inspect elements` on Google and that should give you a great headstart. Good luck :D